# Passing array into urlencode

Tags: php

Trying to get lat and lang for google map and using code below.

```
    $links = [$url1, $url2, $url3];
    $addr = [];
    foreach($links as $link){

        $htm = pageContent($link);
        $paths = new \DOMXPath($htm);
        $routes = $paths->query("table[@class='bgc_line']/tr[3]/td[2]");
        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            $addr = trim($route->nodeValue);
        }

            $address = urlencode($addr);
            $response = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}&key=GOOGLE_API_KEY");
            $result = json_decode($response);

            $lat[] = $result->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
            $lng[] = $result->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
        }
```

But having an error which is `urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` any way to pass an array into urlencode?

Comment: [`trim`](http://www.php.net/trim) returns a string, so the error must come from another part of your code. Btw, that `foreach ($routes as $route)` loop just overwrites `addr` on every iteration, which is a bit suspicious...

Comment: Hm, like you said, there was some array in the loop I solve the problem by fixing it. Thank you.